# WPML & CFT: keeping custom field file to translation

Tags: custom-field, plugin-wpml

i got a wp site with the [WPML](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/) plugin and the [CFT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) plugin. I set up custom fields for posts and what i'm trying to do is to keep the content of an `input type file` from the original post to its translation. That would save time as the pictures are the same between both posts and also save disk space on the ftp.

So far i couldnt get it working, not even to get basic `input type text` automatically pasted from the 1st post to its translation. I tried the different options in WPML > Translation management > Mutlilingual content setup > Custom fields translation without any result.

PS: am using WP 3.1.3, WPML 2.0.4.1 and CFT 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of WPML (version 2.3) has a new module for Media and this module takes care of the previous images issue. 
Now there is no longer the need to upload the same image twice.

Just like copying the content from the original language, it is now also possible to duplicate the images and/or the featured image:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Piet, i'm getting in touch with them to be sure i'd work fine cos this version i a for-sale one. Do you know if this "media module" you speak of is integrated within the whole plugin or is it an add-on to buy or get from them?

Comment: @kevin, the media module is part of the paid version. They offer the paid version as 1 price for all deal, so no hidden fees and additional payments for extended functionality.

Comment: Just got the paid version and so far i cant reach what i'm looking for. I see those checkboxes yes, but when i hit the translate button then the 'import content' button, it does import the content with the media, but not the featured image and the content of all the custom fields. However, when i hit'publish', the feat image does show up. Gona try to get in touch with the support to see if this has any chance to work or not. Thanks for help!

Comment: @kevin you'll need to go into the media settings (of WPML) and process the images first.

Comment: yeah i tried that, the 'Scan and duplicate attachement' button. It gives me back a '0 attachments not processed' instead of 1 for example but when i get back to the post i still dont have the picture into the field. I also tried with another plugin instead of 'Custom field template': http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/. Pretty annoying, seems simple and complicated at the same time...

Comment: @kevin from your answer I understand that you load your images via custom fields? Such "attachments", which really are not attachments at all, WMPL does not export to the translation and instead you can just do a copy and paste yourself.

Comment: Yes i do, using the CFT plugin. Well if those are not attachements, what are they? The site is for a client so i'd like it to be all automatic, would be more professional. I got in touch with the people at the WPML forum and we're trying to sort this out, i'll let you know what solution we came up with, i really wanna solve this. Thanks again for support.

Comment: @kevin, if you would use the native WordPress featured images and/or image attachments all would go automatic for your client. By doing it the custom field way, you're making it more complicated IMHO... I'm sure Amir and Mihai can help you on your way though!

Comment: The problem is that i need each picture to have its own field, cos the client needs to be in control of the order of the pictures (30).

Comment: I finally switched to a simple gallery insertion into the post's content. It allows me to custom the order of the pictures and once published, i can import the content to the translation with the "copy content" button (screenshot here for those interested: http://www.mediafire.com/?5bd7ryc09y32fq3 ). The only little bug still there is that when editing the original gallery's order, you gotta edit the translation's order too. Surprinsingly the gallery's content itself is updated (the images)!

Edit: Big thanks to Piet for the hand!

Comment: glad I could be of help @kevin